# how to do logback level exclusion for custom logger name

Tags: java, log4j, logback

I am trying to exclude log level for custom logger name in logback but it is not taking effect.

This is how the logger initialize below

```java
 Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleTailCommand.class+".EXEC_0");

  @Test
  public void simpleTail() throws Exception {
     logger.info("test1");
  }
```

This is my logback.xml configuration

```
<configuration>


    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger - %thread - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="net.schmizz" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.my.package.SimpleTailCommand.*" level="ERROR"/>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

When i run my program . the logger still print the "info" level